# How non-blocking API works?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, nonblocking

I've been reading [Play Framework documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ThreadPools#Knowing-when-you-are-blocking) and found this quote confusing:

> Note that you may be tempted to therefore wrap your blocking code in
>   Futures. This does not make it non-blocking, it just means the
>   blocking will happen in a different thread. You still need to make
>   sure that the thread pool that you are using has enough threads to
>   handle the blocking.

I was under impression that all those non-blocking libs are doing blocking operations in their own thread pools and return `Future` objects so client code won't be blocking.

But this quote said that it doesn't make it non-blocking. Am I missing something? Is there some advanced magic with non-blocking libs?

Comment: blocking is not "deadlocking". The resource will be locked from its own perspective, but the UI or whatever main thread is doing will not be waiting for it to become unlocked. But the resource *will* be locked when it's accessed. For example, a 2nd thread accessing the same resource will take longer than the first one to complete because it will have to wait for the first one to unlock the resource. Or the resource to unlock itself, depending on the model.

Comment: The whole purpose of Futures or Promises is to smoothen resource access and use. It does not propose an alternate locking mechanism.

Comment: There is difference between async and non-blocking. I hope this link would help you to  understand the difference between these two: http://www.programmr.com/blogs/difference-between-asynchronous-and-non-blocking

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Blocking** (as in **Blocking IO**) in the sense of IO means that the thread which initiated the IO goes to sleep until the IO result is available.

**Non-Blocking IO** (or **Asynchronous IO**) tells the relevant driver (the kernel, a DB driver, etc.) to initialize an IO action and then the thread **keeps on doing other stuff**.  depending on the technology you use, you handle asynchronous IO results (which may be even an exception) in callbacks (such in Node.js) , channels (Java) , futures (C++) , promises (newer versions of Node.js), Tasks (.Net), coroutines(C++17) etc.

Asynchronous IO does not use threads to make the IO asynchronous. this is the key point here. throwing a blocking IO action to the thread-pool will not make it asynchronous, its just blocking on another thread, and very non scalable. it will make the threadpool be drained out of threads because they will just block as more and more blocking IO is submitted. as they write in their documentation:

> The most common place where a typical Play application will block is
>   when it’s talking to a database. Unfortunately, none of the major
>   databases provide asynchronous database drivers for the JVM

meaning that most of the DB implementation do no provide asynchronous IO for Java - throwing a SQL query to a thread-pool will make the thread-pool thread block. this is what they mean by saying :

> Note that you may be tempted to therefore wrap your blocking code in
>   Futures. This does not make it non-blocking, it just means the
>   blocking will happen in a different thread.

as we said before , Asynchronous IO **is not** Blocking IO on another thread.

An example for a **Real** asynchronous IO in Java is provided by the standard package `java.nio`

Comment: One good example of non-blocking IO is anything where you're waiting on hardware to notify you when it's finished. E.g. a driver that sends a block of data off to a hard drive, then returns control to the application immediately so it can do other things, then notifies the application when the write is finished or provides some other mechanism to poll for completion.

Comment: @DavidHaim please take a look at the related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41241983/spring-jersey-async-controller-advantages

Comment: @JasonC `then notifies the application when the write is finished or provides some other mechanism to poll for completion`

How does it notify the application when the write is finished?

Comment: @Ashwin There's a lot of ways to accomplish that, and a lot of different contexts; 
you'd have to read the docs for whatever you're dealing with to find out whatever specific mechanism it's using. :)